# How do I loop through a Spark RDD to evaluate each element in a nested tuple and append that result to the original RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Apologies if this is a beginner question, Im new to PySpark and Python both.

I have this RDD here which is a tuple, it contains the movie IDs as the first element (1,2,3,4...etc) and a string of binary integers as the second element. So the Movie ID is the Key and the Binary integers are the Value.

```
Movie ID,    Genre

1,         (1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)    

2,         (0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
```

And so on.

Each of the binary integers indicates whether that movie ID belongs in a particular genre or not. I want to build a recommender system in PySpark that will take a movie ID of say 50, and compare its binary integers (that indicate which genres it belongs to) to the binary integers of every other movie ID in the RDD. If two binary integers in the same position = 1, some kind of counter would be incremented. The more times a movie ID has a 1 in the same position as a 1 of movie ID 50, the more the counter is incremented. The counter would be stored in a variable that measures how strongly each movie ID matches the genre of the movie ID 50. Because the more times each movie ID has a 1 in the same position as another movie ID, the more closely related their genres are and the stronger the recommendation.

I would then aim to form a new RDD that contains only the Movie ID and the Counter Value as my Key Value Pair, and discard the binary integers entirely.

So that my end result would look more like:

```
MovieID,       Genre

1,            5

2,            3
```

Would appreciate the help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [don't post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5858851).

Comment: removed, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **excellent** case for matrix multiplication. [image]

```
A^T * B will give you the exact counter itself that you want!!
    where A is the matrix of your binary integers in Movie ID 50
          B is the matrix of binary integers in other movie IDs
```

When you have '1' in same position, your matrix multiplication will yield 1, else its going to yield 0 for that position.

so, ex: 1+1+0+.....+1=answer that you exactly want.
You have to aggregateByKey after doing the operations.

Give a try on this logic. You will achieve.
However, provide your dataset. I might be able to give you a code.
Cheers!!

Comment: This was helpful! Thanks! 
Based on your advice I tried the following code:
'genreRDDstr=genreRDD.join(genreRDD).mapValues(lambda x: x[0] * x[movieID])' 
Where movieID is passed into the program using a sys.argv() arguement. 
Unfortunately, I think im still making a mistake somewhere as i am still getting an error.

Comment: *Link to the data set im using*: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WNw_moGkMCMczyOxfDv0ihpEeBKH_eUE. 

*And the link to my code file in its current bugged form*: https://drive.google.com/open?id=136yt0vwSEJrnYof8JRWgCgpDyj4cVhIA

Comment: Link to data set with user IDs and ratings:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l8USANOrIL7F7Q7BoDhscauyqqYcicMo